# Populate choice parameter in jenkinsfile with list of folders in SCM repository

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've got a Jenkinsfile that drives a pipeline which the user must select a specific folder in a bitbucket repo to target. I want that choice parameter dropdown to be dynamically populated.

Currently, I've got the choice param list hardcoded as per this generic example:

```
choice(name: 'IMAGE', choices: ['workload-x','workload-y','workload-z'])
```

I wondered if this is possible from within the jenkinsfile itself, or whether I'd have to create a specific groovy script for this then call it. Either way I'm a bit lost as I'm pretty new to jenkins and have only just started working with Jenkinsfiles.

Some trial and error googling has allowed me to create a groovy script which returns an array of folder names in the repository using json slurper:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class,
        Jenkins.instance,
        null,
        null
    );

def credential = creds.find {it.id == "MYBITBUCKETCRED"}

if (!credential) { return "Unable to pickup credential from Jenkins" }
username = credential.username
pass = credential.password.toString()

def urlStr = "https://bitbucket.mydomain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/MYPROJECT/repos/MYREPO/browse/"

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlStr).openConnection()
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + pass).getBytes("UTF-8"));
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
conn.connect();

def slurper = new JsonSlurper() 
def browseList = slurper.parseText(conn.getInputStream().getText())

def dfList = browseList.children.values.path.name.findAll {it.contains('workload-')}

return dfList
```

This returns a result as follows:

```
Result:   [workload-a,workload-b,workload-c,workload-x,workload-y,workload-z]
```

However I'm unsure how then to call this in my Jenkinsfile in order to populate the dropdown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do it this way (follow my example below) or make use of [Active Choice Jenkins Plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) - because It allows some groovy scripting to prepare your choice

Note- The Choice parameter will be available after a first run.

```
def choiceArray = []
node {
    checkout scm
    def folders = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "ls $WORKSPACE")
    
    folders.split().each {
        //condition to skip files if any
        choiceArray << it
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any;
    parameters { choice(name: 'CHOICES', choices: choiceArray, description: 'Please Select One') }
    stages {
        stage('debug') {
            steps {
                echo "Selected choice is : ${params.CHOICES}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a neat way of doing it and worked perfectly. Thanks Samit.

Comment: How does this work, you run the pipeline, populate the active choices and the you halt the pipeline and fill the choices on the UI? How does that halting work?

Answer (score 1):

I used the previous example to load the list in the same build
I send the command output to a file, to be consumed in the next step

Here the jenkinsfile:

```
def choiceArray = []

pipeline {
 agent any
  parameters {
  string defaultValue: '', description: 'PATH_to_scripts', name: 'SCRIPTPATH', trim: false
  string defaultValue: '', description: 'Optional parameters', name: 'MOREparams', trim: false
  }
 stages {
    stage('show available date') {
      steps {
        sh '''
        echo $JENKINS_HOME
        cd $JENKINS_HOME/scripts
        ./0_db_show_available.sh $DBlike $AWS_PROFILE $DATEFILTER > $JENKINS_HOME/scripts/lista.txt
        echo "Show available date"
        cat $JENKINS_HOME/scripts/lista.txt
        '''
      }
    }
   stage('Restore') {
        steps {
            script {
              def folders = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat $JENKINS_HOME/scripts/lista.txt")    
              //load the array using the file content (lista.txt)
                folders.split().each {
                    choiceArray << it
                }                  
                // wait for user input 
              def INPUT_DATE = input message: 'Please select date', ok: 'Next',
              //generate the list using the array content
              parameters: [ choice(name: 'CHOICES', choices: choiceArray, description: 'Please Select One') ]
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

[samit-kumar-patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4752516/samit-kumar-patel), thanks for first example, it helps me